# move div to first row in bootstrap grid layout

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap grid layout to display div's as below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" ng-if="data1.length"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" ng-if="data2.length"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" ng-if="data3.length"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" ng-if="data4.length"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to move the first div of second row to first row if data2 or data3 length is 0. Is that possible in bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use JavaScript. First you need to define your condition, then place your content into the div.

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="mydiv"></div>
<div class="col-md-4" id="mydiv2"></div>
<!-- and so on -->
<script>
if(data2.length = 0 or data3.length = 0){
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = 'your content';
}
</script>
```

Hope that worked for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

For this case, If the length of data2 and data3 is zero. you can able to use bootstrap visible and hidden classes
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/